# Exclude one color when printing an Adobe Acrobat X document

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I have an image in an acrobat x document with a lot of yellow on it.  I want to print it but not have any yellow print.  I can't figure it out, but the user who asked me this showed me a printout he did last week where the yellow is left out and all the other colors are there.  He doesn't know how he did it and I can't figure it out either.

Comment: Maybe his printer was out of yellow ink? :)